# ndarrayの処理でのforループを使わない方法

Tags: python, numpy

以下のコードでforループを使わない方法を探しています。
5つの2次元ndarrayの平均を求める際に、min-max rejectionを用いる処理です。

```
stack = np.empty((0, 100, 100))
stack = np.append(stack, data1[np.newaxis, :], axis=0)
stack = np.append(stack, data2[np.newaxis, :], axis=0)
stack = np.append(stack, data3[np.newaxis, :], axis=0)
stack = np.append(stack, data4[np.newaxis, :], axis=0)
stack = np.append(stack, data5[np.newaxis, :], axis=0)

amax = np.argmax(stack, axis=0)
amin = np.argmin(stack, axis=0)

mask = np.zeros((5, 100, 100), dtype=bool)

for j in range(100):
    for i in range(100):
        nmax = amax[j, i]
        nmin = amin[j, i]
        mask[nmax, j, i] = True
        mask[nmin, j, i] = True

stack_tmp = np.ma.masked_array(stack, mask=mask)
stack_minmax = np.ma.mean(stack_tmp, axis=0).data
```

Comment: 念のため "forループを使わない" 理由も添えておくと具体的な回答が付きやすくなると思います。

Comment: こんな記事あたりが参考になるかもしれません。[numpy REJECTION before getting median or average of 2D arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26906123/9014308)

Comment: cubickさん、コメントをありがとうございます。「forループを使わない」方法を探す理由は、numpy/ndarrayの理解を深めるためです。ndarrayを使う処理の多くの場合でforループを回避するベクトル的な処理が可能です。上の場合でどのような回避方法があるのかという興味があります。

Comment: kunifさん、コメントをありがとうございます。参考にしてみます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

すでに答え出てそうだけど,
`mask` と同じ内容のものは以下のようにできます

```py
is_min_or_max = (stack == np.min(stack, axis=0))|(stack == np.max(stack, axis=0))

assert np.all(is_min_or_max == mask), '不一致'
display(stack[is_min_or_max])
```

Comment: 回答付ける前の下書きではもう少しコードが長く せっかく調べたしと投稿しましたが, 結局, ほとんどコメントの記事通りになってしまいました

Comment: ありがとうございます。間違いなく同じ結果が得られることを確認しました。そして、期待通りforループ（しかも2重）を回すよりもうんと速くなりました。